# DXA - Sample site

Tags: dxa, web8, dxa-1.4

Web 8.1.1 is installed and DXA 1.4
I tried to setup DXA sample site.
It is configured and site is loading but some parts have an error.

Error
[image]

Error message in log file is

> 2016-05-30 11:03:47,502 [26] ERROR - An error occurred while resolving evidence using the Context Service.
>   Sdl.Web.Common.DxaException: An error occurred while resolving evidence using the Context Service. ---> Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceTransportException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8087
>      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
>      at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>      at Microsoft.OData.Client.HttpWebRequestMessage.GetResponse()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your context service up and running and well configured? The discovery and content services seem okay from the screenshot, your issue seem to be in the context service for images.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. I followed instructions on SDL Web 8 Standalone installation and there was nothing related to context service. I installed it now and everything is ok. Thanks one more time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution: Context service wasn't installed. So after installation of that service everything works fine

Comment: Please mark your own Answer as such.

Answer (score 1):

The error suggests a connection issue, Can you access your Discovery Service from the machine you are debugging from?

Possible causes (and there could be a lot)

1. Incorrect value for discovery-service-uri in web.config, shown below
2. Discovery service incorrectly configured
3. Firewall blocking Discovery service, as it runs on "unusual" port number (8087?)
4. If enabled, incorrectly configured OAuth

> ```
>   <add key="discovery-service-uri" value="http://saintjohn11.ams.dev:8082/discovery.svc" />
> ```

Comment: Web config has good value, also in `cd_client.log` there is message 2016-05-30 12:48:31 INFO [Sdl.Web.Delivery.ContentService.AutoConfigure.get_ODataV4ServiceEndpoint] - content-service endpoint found from discovery service.                                                      Discovery service is configured good. Firewall is not blocking Discovery service.