# DXA 1.4 Java: facing issue with services installed on Linux service

Tags: content-delivery, dxa, web8, dxa-java, infrastructure

We are facing issue with DXA Java 1.4.
We have installed all services (i.e. discovery, Session, Context) to Linux server.
When we add discovery service URL to `cd_client_conf.xml` and `CWD_client_conf.xml`.

It throws null exception and data is not appearing on the page.

Moreover with similar settings we installed all services to windows server and add discovery URL to both configuration files we are able to get data on page.

We also tried combination of these 2 services like in `cd_client_conf.xml` we added discovery service URL of linux server and in `cwd_client_conf.xml` we added discovery service URL of windows server, then page is coming fine with data coming from linux discovery service.

Can you please help me what is the dependency of `cwd_Client_conf.xml` file for the rendering of the page and what we have missed on Linux server to install these services.

Configuration settings:

[image]

We went ahead and applied all the Hotfixes available on Web 8.1.1 version.
CD_8.1.1.1752.zip,
CD_8.1.1.1876.zip,
CD_8.1.1.1957.zip, 
CD_8.1.1.2049.zip,
CD_8.1.1.2121.zip

Still we are facing same issue with Context service installed on Linux: Error logs:

> 2016-07-22 16:56:08,742 [27] ERROR - An error occurred while resolving evidence using the Context Service.
>   Sdl.Web.Common.DxaException: An error occurred while resolving evidence using the Context Service. ---> Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQueryException: An error occurred while processing this request. ---> Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceClientException: BadRequest
>      at Microsoft.OData.Client.QueryResult.ExecuteQuery()
>      at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents)
>      at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQuerySingle`1.GetValue()
>      at Sdl.Web.Context.OData.Client.Caller.IoDataContextEngineServiceCaller.Resolve(String serialisedEvidence)
>      at Sdl.Web.Context.OData.Client.ODataContextEngine.Resolve(IEvidence evidence)
>      at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Context.ContextServiceClaimsProvider.GetContextClaims(String aspectName)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Context.ContextServiceClaimsProvider.GetContextClaims(String aspectName)
>      at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Context.ContextEngine..ctor()
>      at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Configuration.WebRequestContext.get_ContextEngine()
>      at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Configuration.WebRequestContext.get_MaxMediaWidth()
>      at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Html.BaseMediaHelper.GetResponsiveWidth(String widthFactor, Int32 containerSize)
>      at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Html.BaseMediaHelper.GetResponsiveImageUrl(String url, Double aspect, String widthFactor, Int32 containerSize)
>      at Sdl.Web.Common.Models.Image.ToHtml(String widthFactor, Double aspect, String cssClass, Int32 containerSize)
>      at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Html.HtmlHelperExtensions.Media(HtmlHelper helper, MediaItem media, String widthFactor, Double aspect, String cssClass, Int32 containerSize)
>      at ASP._Page_Areas_Ceair_Views_Entity_HeroBannerHeadingLeft_cshtml.Execute() in Page\Areas\Ceair\Views\Entity\HeroBannerHeadingLeft.cshtml:line 8

Due to this context service issue  Images are not rendering with DXA.Net 1.4 but content is coming fine. 
and With Java DXA 1.4 we are getting internal server issue on the page.

Context Service Output and access from my local system:
[image]

We have tried the workaround steps mentioned by Rick:

We have updated Content(Session) Service with the help of these 2 
Urls:
http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-65379730-BB26-4712-B104-B467BD0C23D0#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-7C6C74E2-DC82-4EFF-87B8-C7509E5F0C92.xml&docid=GUID-7C6C74E2-DC82-4EFF-87B8-C7509E5F0C92&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-7C6C74E2-DC82-4EFF-87B8-C7509E5F0C92

http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v5/GUID-9127A28E-5DF8-45C9-B64D-2EC2C5280195#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-9127A28E-5DF8-45C9-B64D-2EC2C5280195.xml&docid=GUID-9127A28E-5DF8-45C9-B64D-2EC2C5280195&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-9127A28E-5DF8-45C9-B64D-2EC2C5280195

We are getting following error when starting content(session) service.

> 2016-07-26 15:22:01,045 ERROR PersistentContextRepository - Context repository rules have not been pre-initialised in context repository, spin up will be slightly slower.  Please re-initialise your repository.
>   2016-07-26 15:22:11,649 ERROR EngineFactory - Unable to configure the AmbientData Framework
>   com.tridion.configuration.ConfigurationException: Cannot find claim processor configuration provider class: com.sdl.context.ambient.ContextEngineClaimProcessorConfigProvider
>       at com.tridion.ambientdata.EngineFactory.claimProcessorDefinitionFromConfig(EngineFactory.java:101) ~[web-ambient-engine-8.1.1-1005.jar:8.1.1-1005]
>       at com.tridion.ambientdata.EngineFactory.cartridgeDefinitionFromConfig(EngineFactory.java:70) ~[web-ambient-engine-8.1.1-1005.jar:8.1.1-1005]
>       at com.tridion.ambientdata.EngineFactory.newEngine(EngineFactory.java:45) ~[web-ambient-engine-8.1.1-1005.jar:8.1.1-1005]
>       at com.sdl.web.content.ambient.service.AmbientServiceProvider.init(AmbientServiceProvider.java:53) [content-ambient-extension-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:300) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) [spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) [spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at com.sdl.delivery.service.ServiceContainer.main(ServiceContainer.java:43) [service-container-core-8.1.1-1007.jar:8.1.1-1007]
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sdl.context.ambient.ContextEngineClaimProcessorConfigProvider
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
>       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
>       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
>       at com.tridion.ambientdata.EngineFactory.claimProcessorDefinitionFromConfig(EngineFactory.java:97) ~[web-ambient-engine-8.1.1-1005.jar:8.1.1-1005]
>       ... 25 common frames omitted
>   2016-07-26 15:22:12,433 ERROR SpringApplication - Application startup failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ambientServiceProvider': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.sdl.odata.api.processor.datasource.ODataDataSourceException: Error while initialising Ambient Data Framework

Thanks
Piyush Jain

Comment: similar issue: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14750/dxa-sample-site/14754

Comment: I have seen this block, But still not found any solution yet.

Comment: It looks like your context service, while installed, isn't actually working. Have you tried accessing it directly yourself to see what kind of errors you get? Have you checked the logs for the context service?

Comment: Updated output of Context service

Comment: Apparently, the Context Service on Linux is sending a Bad Request (400) response. Do you see a trace of this  in the Context Service log files?

Answer (score 1):

Given your analysis, this seems like a defect in the Context Service (client). I would recommend reporting this to SDL Customer Support for further analysis and resolution.

As a work-around, you can configure DXA to get the Context Claims from ADF instead of from Context Service:

- For DXA Java: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v5/GUID-9127A28E-5DF8-45C9-B64D-2EC2C5280195
- For DXA .NET: configure `AdfContextClaimsProvider` instead of `ContextServiceClaimsProvider` in `Unity.config`

If you do this, you have to ensure that you enable the Context Cartridge in your Content Service. In that manner the Context Claims are provided by the Content Service instead of the Context Service.

Such an ADF-based configuration is known to have worse performance, so should be considered a work-around.

Comment: Thanks Rick but after following the steps we are not able to start content (Session) service. Error logs added above

Comment: We have updated Content(Session) Service with the help of these 2 Urls:

Answer (score 1):

There is a known issue in the Unix `start.sh` script for the Context Service which can cause 400 errors if the user-agent string contains encoded slashes. The workaround is to add the following Java System Properties to the top of the `start.sh` script:

```
JVM_OPTIONS="-Xrs -Xms256m -Xmx256m -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true -Dorg.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.ALLOW_BACKSLASH=true"
```

This property is already set in the Windows startup scripts, and will be addressed in the Unix startup script in future versions. Note that this might also impact you if you are running a load balancer in front of your service - as these may also reject these encoded slashes in the parameters. This will also be addressed in a future release (via double-encoding).

Comment: Yes After this fix we are able to run page with Linux hosted service.

Answer (score 0):

After adding this parameters with JVM_Options, we are able to resolve this issue. Please let me know when we get any further update on this. Thanks a lot.